# How to create beans of the same class for multiple template parameters in Spring

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-bean

I want to send events and messages of different object types using Kafka topics. So I have producer configuration class in which I create the beans of the class `KafkaTemplate` and `ProducerFactory`:

```
@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, BeltMessage> kafkaBeltMessageTemplate(final ProducerFactory<String, BeltMessage> producerFactory) {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory);
}

@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaStringTemplate(final ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory) {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory);
}

@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, BeltEventDescription> kafkaBeltEventDescriptionTemplate(final ProducerFactory<String, BeltEventDescription> producerFactory) {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory);
}

@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, BeltItemEvent> kafkaBeltItemEventTemplate(final ProducerFactory<String, BeltItemEvent> producerFactory) {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory);
}

@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, BeltMessage> producerBeltMessageFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(Map.of(
            ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress,
            ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class,
            ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class
    ));
}

@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerStringFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(Map.of(
            ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress,
            ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class,
            ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class
    ));
}

@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, BeltEventDescription> producerBeltEventDescriptionFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(Map.of(
            ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress,
            ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class,
            ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class
    ));
}

@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, BeltItemEvent> producerBeltItemEventFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(Map.of(
            ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress,
            ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class,
            ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class
    ));
}
```

Now, it's the same implementation for everyone of them and it's just code duplicated for each bean separately, the only change is the template parameter.

Is there a way to create a generic bean like `KafkaTemplate<String, Object>`? I tried to abstract out an interface from `BeltItemEvent` and `BeltEventDescription`, but then I got an error in runtime because it could not be serialized by Kafka.

> `Servlet.service()` for servlet [`dispatcherServlet]` in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: `org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException`: Can't convert value of class `com.example.events.BeltEventDescription` to class `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer` specified in `value.serializer`] with root cause
> `java.lang.ClassCastException`: class `com.example.events.BeltEventDescription` cannot be cast to class `java.lang.String` (`com.example.events.BeltEventDescription` is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; `java.lang.String` is in module `java.base` of loader 'bootstrap')

But there is a lot of code duplication in case I want to create new events that declare the various contracts I might need in the future.

Comment: You need to use the correct serializer, as the error message suggests. You're having a `BeltEventDescription` but you're trying to use a `StringSerializer` for the value

Comment: @QBrute I changed to JsonSerializer, `ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class,
                ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class` but I still get Kafka Exception `No method found for class java.lang.String`